# USB redirection not working for remote Windows Server 2012

Tags: usb, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an issue where I'm running some software on a virtual Windows Server 2012 R2. The software requires a USB license dongle to be plugged in to the machine before the software can start. When I try remoting into the server from my computer running Windows 10, I am not able to redirect the USB dongle to the server.

Is there something different about Windows Server that doesn't like USB devices? This issue is not limited to just the USB license dongle, I can't redirect any USB devices to the server.

I followed the directions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719489/how-to-enable-usb-redirection-in-windows-10), but this did not solve the issue. The dongle does not appear in Devices and Printers on the server. I worked through [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2653326/some-usb-devices-are-not-available-through-remotefx-usb-redirection) on how to enable redirection for some USB devices and the USB device [shows up properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzdVQ.png) in the list of local devices and resources. But the server doesn't get it.